# Using procedure as data source for ReusableStreamDecode filter

Tags: postscript

Acc. to the PostScript spec, page 124, the data source of a decoding filter can be a procedure.

It says:

> The procedure must return on the operand stack a readable string
> containing any number of bytes of data. The filter pops this string
> from the stack and uses its contents as input to the filter. This process repeats until the
> filter encounters end-of-data (EOD).

Here is an example PS file with a string literal used as data source:

```
%!

/myDataSource (Hello ABC!) /ReusableStreamDecode filter def

% testing random access
myDataSource dup 6 setfileposition read {==} if % 65 A
myDataSource dup 0 setfileposition read {==} if % 72 H
myDataSource dup 8 setfileposition read {==} if % 67 C
```

How does a PS procedure have to be crafted that can be used as data source instead of a string? In this way I want to side-step the size limit (65535 characters) of PostScript strings. (After all, I want to define a function of `/FunctionType 0` with a `/DataSource <file>` entry, where `<file>` is a repositionable file object larger than the string size limit.)

Comment: Here is an article about CreateDataArray procedure to read data from a file and place into an array of strings: http://www.acumentraining.com/Acumen_Journal/AcumenJournal_Feb2003.zip and the previous two months articles discuss ReusableStreamDecode for more info.

Comment: @beginner6789 The article looks very interesting and might give a solution to my problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: @beginner6789 Thank you once more! I added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is based on the [article](http://www.acumentraining.com/Acumen_Journal/AcumenJournal_Feb2003.zip) pointed to by user [beginner6789](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10581654/beginner6789).

In essence, data is provided as an array of strings, which extends the upper limit to 64K²=4G of data, which is fairly much. (PostScript arrays have the same limit of 65535 elements, like PostScript strings.)

The procedure that is to replace the single, literal string used as data source in the original code gets one string from the array at a time and pushes it on the operand stack when called by the filter. We need to keep track of the array index of the element that was last retrieved. The index variable is defined in `userdict` and updated whenever the procedure is executed. Also it is worth noting that an empty string, `()`, must be placed as the last element into the array. It signals End-of-Data to the filter:

```
%!

/myDataArray [(Hello) ( ) (A) (BC) (!) ()] def
userdict /idx 0 put

/myDataSource {myDataArray idx get /idx idx 1 add store} /ReusableStreamDecode filter def

% testing random access
myDataSource dup 6 setfileposition read {==} if % 65 A
myDataSource dup 0 setfileposition read {==} if % 72 H
myDataSource dup 8 setfileposition read {==} if % 67 C
```